# percolation permeability threshold in Helium before and after lambda point transition

Tags: surface-tension, viscosity, capillary-action

There's an experiment demonstrating the properties of super-fluid Helium compared to normal fluid Helium, in which the Helium is put in a jar who's bottom is porous.

The super-fluid can pass through the small capillaries, while the normal fluid can not.

Another experiment uses a fine grained powder (implying the same holds for percolation through porous medium as wall as though the capillaries)

The video of this experiment can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/sKOlfR5OcB4?t=16m53s)

My question is:

Is the permeability threshold determined only by the viscosity of the fluid? Doesn't surface tension also play a role in determining whether the liquid will percolate?

Or do they implicitly assume there's no difference in surface tension between the two phases?

Mercury has similar viscosity as water, with a much higher surface tension - and it will not get absorbed in fine sand, while water will - isn't it because water wets the send, while mercury does not?